# How to toggle a Button Inside a table View

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a custom cell in my table view which contain a button and name of audio file. when i am tapping in button the relevant audio is playing and when tapping again it audio stops. My problem is when i am tapping the same button it is ok but when i am tapping in any button different then current cell then my process is not working. Can any one show me the right direction to do this . My code is below . Thanks in advance..

```
var isAudioPlaying = false

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {     
        return designCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)    
    }

private func designCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell: UITableViewCell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ExtendedDesign", owner: self, options: nil)[4] as! UITableViewCell     
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.height)         
    cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds      
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None    

    btnPlayPause = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! subclassedUIButton        
    btnPlayPause.addTarget(self, action: "btnPlayPauseTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)              
    btnPlayPause.urlString = arrAttractionList[indexPath.row].audio.url             
    let lblAttractionName = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel          
    lblAttractionName.text = arrAttractionList![indexPath.row].name     
    return cell     
}
```

My Button Methode is:

```
func btnPlayPauseTapped(sender: subclassedUIButton) {    

    if !isAudioPlaying {      
        isAudioPlaying = true       
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Button_Pause"), forState: .Normal)      
        AudioHandler.sharedManager().playAudio(sender.urlString)                 
    } else {     
        isAudioPlaying = false     
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Button_Play_Menu.png"), forState: .Normal)   
        AudioHandler.sharedManager().audioPlayer?.pause()      
    }    
}
```

// Custome class for UIButton

```
class subclassedUIButton: UIButton {      

    var indexPath: Int?        
    var urlString: String?       
}
```

Comment: Can you please also include the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath, where you are calling your method designCellAtIndexPath

Comment: O sorry i have edited my question. please review

Comment: "but when i am tapping in any button different then current cell then my process is not working"  ------what this mean

Comment: when i am selecting a button other then cell which is selected now then its not working

Comment: Why are you using `loadNibNamed` rather than `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I did it here is my code to do this. First Declare Two variables in class:**

var currentCellIndex :int = -1
var previousCellIndex : int = -1

```
 func btnPlayPauseTapped(sender: subclassedUIButton) {    

    currentCellIndex = sender.indexPath!      
    if currentCellIndex == previousCellIndex {
        if !isAudioPlaying {                
            isAudioPlaying = true
            AudioHandler.sharedManager().stopAudioPlayer()
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Button_Play_Menu.png"), forState: .Normal)
        } else {               
            isAudioPlaying = false
            AudioHandler.sharedManager().playAudio(sender.urlString)
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Button_Pause"), forState: .Normal)
        }

    } else {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: previousCellIndex, inSection: 0)
        tblAttractinList.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        isAudioPlaying = false
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Button_Pause"), forState: .Normal)
        AudioHandler.sharedManager().playAudio(sender.urlString)
        previousCellIndex = sender.indexPath!
    }
}
```

**Thank You all of you for your help! :)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage other flag for your current cell's audio you have to play. Set current cell index and manage that.

Comment: I have added a flag for isaudioPlaying but i am confused how to set flag for this condition can you show me some example code??

Comment: var isAudioPlaying = false;
var currentcellindex = -1

private func designCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    btnPlayPause.tag = indexPath.row
    currentcellindex = indexPath.row
    ...
}
In btnPlayPauseTapped() method if currentcellindex == [sender tag] match with data then Play/Pause that audio and stop other audio.
Check appropriate syntax i have not check.

Comment: Thanks @Nimisha, This code did not work but i got the idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ExtendedDesign", owner: self, options: nil)[4] as! UITableViewCell
```

This is not the correct way to add a cell to a table view. You should call `registerNib(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` (usually in the `viewDidLoad()` method) and then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` delegate method.

The `registerNib(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` isn't needed if you design your cell with a template in the storyboard.

But you really need to use table views the way they were designed to be used. What you have now might seem to work, but it's going to have problems and make your life miserable if you don't use table views the way they were intended to be used.

Also, you don't want to be referencing your subviews with `viewWithTag(_:)`. You want to wire up proper IBOutlets in Interface Builder. Or at least creating properties in your `UITableView` subclass to access the subviews.

Comment: actually it is a slide menu which is coming from a view  thats why i have used this code.

Comment: Are you adding the cells to a UITableView? Or just adding them as subviews to some other type of view?

Comment: i am adding cell to a table view

Comment: Then it doesn't matter if it's a side menu. You really want to construct it properly to avoid problems.

Comment: can you give me idea or sample or any link if available to solve this problem??

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/119642/video-tutorial-table-views-in-ios-series-introduction